# Caffe: How to train end-to-end (image to image)?

Tags: neural-network, caffe, conv-neural-network

We are quite new to [caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/), but what we have seen so far, looks really promising.

After reading a few papers ([1](http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597),[2](https://github.com/s9xie/hed)), we wanted to reproduce the result of [1](http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597), specifically about a segmentation challenge [4](http://brainiac2.mit.edu/isbi_challenge/home).

We downloaded the modified caffe from [3](http://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/people/ronneber/u-net/) and were able to execute it, just to see, that the trained network didn't work with the dataset from [4](http://brainiac2.mit.edu/isbi_challenge/home).

At first we thought that the network needs to be trained for the specific problem. 
Which lead to the problem of how to do 'image-to-image (aka end-to-end) learning ' ([4](http://brainiac2.mit.edu/isbi_challenge/home), training data).

This lead us to 'holistically nested edge detection' (hed, [2](https://github.com/s9xie/hed)), where image-to-image learning, seems to be used.
With hed, we were able to retrain the network on our own. But it doesn't work (it leads to all 0 or 0.5 images - black images :-( ) if we try to train the network for the dataset of [4](http://brainiac2.mit.edu/isbi_challenge/home). For initialization we wrote a script to calculate the mean-map witch we use for the dataset of [4](http://brainiac2.mit.edu/isbi_challenge/home).

**Our question(s) are:**

- How can we reproduce the result, mentioned in [1](http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597) by running
  image-to-image training?

*or*

- How do you train networks, where we have image-to-image learning?
- Since we only have 30 image-to-image pairs, should we implement
  deformation as mentioned in [1](http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597)/[3](http://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/people/ronneber/u-net/) via matlab/python or is there a
  functionality within caffe already?
- Are we missing something simple from [1](http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597) or [2](https://github.com/s9xie/hed)?

Kind regards,
Klaus and Bernhard

Ps: We asked the same question at the caffe-user group and intend to post solutions at both [locations](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/RrO0Y4e3AbQ).

Comment: please link this question to the one you posted on the caffe user group.

Comment: updated 'locations' with https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/RrO0Y4e3AbQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, and trying several different things out - i stumbled upon:

https://github.com/naibaf7

Using that caffe fork, with caffe_neural_models and caffe_neural_tool training image(raw)-to-image(labels) can be done quite simple.

Just check out 'caffe_neural_models/net*' for different configurations.